# Prove that there exist formal deductions whose conclusions are given by $\vdash(ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2}) → (ϕ_{2} \wedge ϕ_{1})$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Prove that there exist formal deductions whose conclusions are the following.
In this exercise, you are not allowed to use the completeness theorem. But you
may use the deduction theorem. Here is the sheet we used for all Axioms and inference rules P1-P9 [All Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUbFg.png)

1. $\vdash(ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2}) → (ϕ_{2} \wedge ϕ_{1})$
2. $(ϕ → ψ, ϕ → θ)\vdash ϕ → (ψ ∧ θ)$

This is what i tried for the first one

> $\vdash (ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2}) → (ϕ_{2} \wedge ϕ_{1})$ by the deduction theorem it is sufficient to find a deduction of $(ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2}) \vdash (ϕ_{2} \wedge ϕ_{1})$
>
> $\psi_{1}:(ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2})$ by assumption
>
> $\psi_{2}: ϕ_{2} \rightarrow( ϕ_{1}\rightarrow ϕ_{2}\wedge ϕ_{1})$ by instantiation of P4
>
> $\psi_{3}: (ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2}) \rightarrow ϕ_{1}$ By instantiation of P3
>
> $\psi_{3}: (ϕ_{1} \wedge ϕ_{2}) \rightarrow ϕ_{2}$
>
> How can i continue here? Because i did not get $(ϕ_{2} \wedge ϕ_{1})$

Here is what i tried for the second one

> By the deduction theorem it is sufficient to find a deduction of  $(ϕ → ψ, ϕ → θ,ϕ)\vdash  (ψ ∧ θ)$
>
> $\psi_{1}: ϕ $ by assumption
>
> $\psi_{2}:ϕ → ψ $ by assumption
>
> $\psi_{3}: ψ$ by MP of $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$
>
> $\psi_{4}: ϕ → θ$ by assumption
>
> $\psi_{4}: θ$ by MP of $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{4}$
>
> How can i continue here....?

Comment: In the first case all that remains is to use MP a few times. In the second one you need another P4 instance and again doing the obvious MPs.

Comment: I'm really curious how you even thought to derive the particular formulas you have already derived if those continuations have _not_ been your plan all along. Are you really really sure that you have done the work yourself? As it is, it looks to me like you're paraphrasing a "complete these proofs" exercise to make it look like you have done some work yourself ...

Comment: no thats kinda what i have derived from similar exercises we have done in class

Comment: @Henning Makholm how do you mean use MP a couple of times in the first one. And here is the original exercise https://imgur.com/RjPllMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Henning said, it's really just a bunch of MP's once you have the relevant instantiations of the relevant axioms .. which you already got:

1. $\phi_{1} \wedge \phi_{2}$ by assumption
2. $\phi_{2} \rightarrow( \phi_{1}\rightarrow (\phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1}))$ by instantiation of P5
3. $(\phi_{1} \wedge \phi_{2}) \rightarrow \phi_{1}$ By instantiation of P3
4. $(\phi_{1} \wedge \phi_{2}) \rightarrow \phi_{2}$ By instantiation of P4
5. $\phi_{1} $ MP 1,3
6. $\phi_{2} $ MP 1,4
7. $\phi_{1}\rightarrow (\phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1})$ MP 2,6
8. $\phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1}$ MP 5,7

So now we've shown $\phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1} \vdash \phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1}$, and so by the Deduction Theorem we get $(\phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1}) \rightarrow (\phi_{2}\wedge \phi_{1})$

Can you now do the second one yourself?